# bloom-release: Failed to open pull request

Tags: ros, bloom-release, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run `bloom-release` command, to release a package for the first time, everything goes well, until the automatic pull request to rosdistro, where i get: `Failed to open pull request: KeyError - 'release'`.

This is what I get at the end of the file `~/.bloom_logs/bloom-release_current-date.log`:

```
[debug] /tmp/tmpIUPSBY:$ git ls-tree master:tracks.yaml
[debug] /tmp/tmpIUPSBY:$ git show master:tracks.yaml
[debug] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/release.py", line 767, in perform_release
    pull_request_url = open_pull_request(track, repository, distro, ssh_pull_request)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/release.py", line 418, in open_pull_request
    updated_distribution_file = generate_ros_distro_diff(track, repository, distro)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/bloom/commands/release.py", line 281, in generate_ros_distro_diff
    repo = distribution_dict['repositories'][repository]['release']
KeyError: 'release'

[error] Failed to open pull request: KeyError - 'release'
[error] SYS.EXIT
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126781/bloom-release:-failed-to-open-pull-request/) by [czalidis](https://answers.ros.org/users/10926/czalidis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2014-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a failure which should have been fixed with this commit:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/commit/9591792a74d4988fdbcc8986438d673a477af7b0

But is still failing in the case that you have an entry (source or doc) but not a release entry yet in the distribution file.

Can you open a ticket against bloom please?

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues

**EDIT:**

I have released `bloom-0.4.9` which should address this problem.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [czalidis](https://answers.ros.org/users/10926/czalidis/) on 2014-02-06**:
Yes, in my case I have already indexed my packages for doc generation. I opened an issue on github, https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/229 .